# Agregar campo de mysql a textbox de vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Estoy tratando de agregar la suma de "Total_Horas_Por_Dia" al textbox de abajo "Total de horas" ya antes he agregado campos de una tabla de mysql a los textbox como el nombre y horario, pero con la sumatoria de los campos no he podido, ¿se deberá a que es un campo calculado (no es directo de la DB)?

Realizado por la siguiente sentencia:

```
"SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Fecha,DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_entrada,'%r') AS Hora_Entrada,DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_salida,'%r') AS Hora_Salida, SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*60) AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia FROM asistencia JOIN prestadores ON prestadores.matricula=' " & matricula.Text & " 'AND asistencia.matricula='" & matricula.Text & "' WHERE asistencia.fecha BETWEEN '" & FechaInicio & "' AND '" & FechaFinal & "';"
```

Tengo la consulta para la sumatoria:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , hora_entrada, hora_salida ))*60)) AS horas_realizadas FROM asistencia WHERE matricula=222222222 AND fecha BETWEEN "2019-06-06" AND "2019-06-12"

**Sale como resultado:
+------------------+
| horas_realizadas |
+------------------+
| 16:35:00         |
+------------------+**
```

y es lo que quiero agregar a ese textbox

pero como dije anteriormente, no se si no se pueda agregar al textbox debido a que es un campo calculado.

[image: Reporte]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si, se puede como con cualquier otro campo. Estas recibiendo alguna clase de error o algo con lo que podamos trabajar? porque asi como esta, mucho no te podemos decir.

Comment: Y como nota, no es ni un campo temporal (no existe ese concepto) y por campo generado, si te refieres a que no es directo de un campo de la DB, no importa para la consulta, porque es lo que devuelve...